# Maximum number of access tokens exceeded:Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have been using docuisgn Api to create and send template and using SOBO concept from past 1 month or so, but now suddenly I am getting error while generating access token for the Generic Account i.e "Maximum number of access tokens exceeded", I read a post regarding saving the access token & reusing it but I read that too that Access token get expired after 15 min or something. Please help on this guys.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly two different topics in play here but with similar vernacular. From the sounds of what you built you may want to consider option 2 below.

1) OAuth2 token which does not expire, which are useful if you are building a native application for a device, or a deep integration. There is a maximum of 10 tokens and you can revoke them via the API or web app. Documentation below.

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/General%20Usage%20Notes.htm

2) OAuth2 token with SAML. Used for short lived authentication approaches for your application in order to avoid using username/passwords to generate authentication tokens (since SAML is used instead). These tokens last 1 hour, no refresh of the token supported.

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/OAuth2%20and%20SAML.htm?Highlight=token

Comment: Thanks a lot Luis,So after doing all the functionality, I need to call the revoke access token Api at the end every time I generate it right ??

Comment: Hi Luis, I am submitting a post request  (POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/oauth2/revoke ) after every time I create the envelope .

Comment: Hi Luis, I am submitting a post request (POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/oauth2/revoke ) after every time I create the envelope But after I log in to Docusign I am still getting the entries to revoke token under connected apps page. Please confirm on this , is this ok to have entries there on anything need to be done

Comment: For option 1, these are non-expiring tokens. I think you only revoke if the application is no longer relevant or if you want to force the user to re-authenticate. For option 2, these are short lived tokens and revocation is not relevant.